# Small Memory Issue with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, delegates, protocols

I made a Mac OS X app that basically runs an NSTask. The thing is, I made a class called XXTask to handle a file, and a class called XXController to handle the drag and drops in the GUI and asking the XXTask to handle a file now and then.

I had made almost the same thing in the past, and it worked fine. This time, I added a delegate protocol, and made XXController the delegate of XXTask.

When XXTask fails, I ask the delegate to show a particular view, and thus call a method like this :

```
[delegate showView];
```

This works, but when trying to relaunch using the information I stored on the first launch, the app outputs errors. I used NSLog to see what exactly was wrong, and it seems like three instance variables (two NSStrings and one NSMutableArray) are (null).

***These are the three instance variables :***

```
NSString *curFilePath;
NSArray *lastArgs;
NSString *lastLaunchPath;
```

***I create them like this :***

```
curFilePath = filename; 
// filename is an NSString passed to the method where I first create curFilePath
// the object passed to the method is a retained NSString (an instance variable of XXController) 
lastArgs = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:curFilePath, [curFilePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent], nil] retain];
lastLaunchPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxtask" ofType:@""] retain];
```

All three variables are null, but the XXTask object is not, as it can still execute code.

***Errors :***

```
2011-01-15 16:38:57.233 App[24179:a0f] PATH : (null)
2011-01-15 16:40:52.846 App[24212:a0f] LAST ARGS : (null)
2011-01-15 16:40:52.847 App[24212:a0f] LAST LP : (null)
2011-01-15 16:40:52.847 App[24212:a0f] Exception detected while handling key input.
2011-01-15 16:40:52.848 App[24212:a0f] *** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)
```

When I don't draw the view by calling the delegate, everything is okay. I could put that view method in the XXTask class, but I'd rather find a neat explanation to this first. What happens when I call the delegate? (It's the first time I tried using delegate protocols)

Thanks for answering!

*If this code looks horrible to you, I have two excuses :*

1. I've been messing around for a long
   time, read the memory management
   docs and did the most silly things.
2. Reference-count memory management is quite new to me. I've
   never made real big apps like this
   one in the past, so I normally can't
   do a lot wrong, but this time memory
   is way more important.

Comment: Could you paste the errors into this question?

Comment: Added my three NSLogs to show the objects are nil, and two errors that are completely normal because XXLastArgs is null (I'm making an array with XXLastArgs and adding an object to that array, and as XXLastArgs is nil, this outputs an error).

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the @interfaces — it's pretty hard to just _guess_ what belongs where... Where and how do you set up and connect the delegate relationship? Could it be that you simply disposed of your XXTask after the NSTask failed and recreated it through some sort of lazy loading logic gone wrong? If your ivars were over-released you'd most certainly be crashing and not seing null's there...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correct (it's pretty hard without any code) you store some information held in XXTask, right?

Do you retain/copy the data? If not, it gets released as soon the XXTask gets released.
If I misunderstand your question, I ask you to provide some code which demonstrates your problem. This makes finding errors much easier.

Comment: I would love to give code, but it's not that easy. I don't know where the problem is exactly, so I don't know what code to give you. I'm gonna edit my post to clarify some things. Thanks for answering!